# awk to match field between two files and use conditions on match

Tags: awk

I am trying to look for `$2` of `file1` (skipping the header) in `$2` of `file2` and if they match and the value in `$10` is `>` 30 and `$11` is `>` 49, then print the line to a `output` file.  The below `awk` has syntax errors in it though `shellcheck` didn't return any.  Both the input and output are `tab-delimited`.  I think the below is close, but not sure what is wrong.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{A[$2];next}$2 in A
{if($10 >.5 OFS $11 > 49)
print ; next
' file1 file2
awk: cmd. line:2: {if($10 >.5 OFS $11 > 49)
awk: cmd. line:2:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3: print ; next
awk: cmd. line:3:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

**file1**

```
Missing in IDP but found in Reference:
2   166848646   G   A   exonic  SCN1A   68  13  16;20   0;0 17;15   0;0 0;0 0;0     c.[5139C>T]+[=] 52.94
```

**file2**

```
chr2    166245425   SCN2A   AMPL5155065355  SNP Het C/T C   T   54  100   50    23  27
chr2    166848646   SCN1A   AMPL1543060606  SNP Het        G/A   G  A   52.9411764706   100 68  32  36
```

**desired output**

```
2   166848646   G   A   exonic  SCN1A   68  13  16;20   0;0 17;15   0;0 0;0 0;0     c.[5139C>T]+[=] 52.94
```

edit with new `awk`

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{A[$2];next}$2 in A {
if($10 >.5 OFS $11 > 49) >>> if($10 >.5 && $11 > 49)
print }
' file1 file2 > out
awk: cmd. line:2: if($10 >.5 OFS $11 > 49) >>> if($10 >.5 && $11 > 49)
awk: cmd. line:2:                    ^ syntax error
```

Comment: One quick thing: `if($10 >.5 OFS $11 > 49)` >>>  `if($10 >.5 && $11 > 49)`

Comment: Also, the `next` after the `print` does nothing, so you can remove it. Then you should add the missing closing `}` before the closing `'`.

Comment: added the edit with new `awk` but getting a syntax error though `shellcheck` detected no errors.  Thank you :).

Comment: Sorry! By ">>>" I meant to replace one with the other --- I should have been more explicit about that. In any case, looks like @karafka has the answer for you, below.

Comment: I am reading that, among other books to try and understand better ways of handling my large scientific datasets.  I am learning slowly but still make mistakes. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} 
                          ($2 in a) && $10>30 && $11>49 ' file1 file2
```